# What is a generic name to cover arccosine, cosine, and sine?

Tags: terminology

I am writing a simple application to plot the curves of arccosine, cosine, and sine for learning purposes and would like to know if there is a generic phrase or wording I can use for the name of the application that relates to all three?

I believe that `trigonometry` is too vague in this context since I'm not covering the entire subject but a subset of the subject.

Comment: Trigonometry..?

Comment: @CameronWilliams Thank you for the suggestion but I believe that would be too vague since they are subsets of the subject as a whole.

Comment: @Gnumbertester would that imply functions such as `tangent` or others?

Comment: There are six commonly used trig functions, several more obscure ones, and the various inverse functions. Surely you cannot expect there to be special terms to denote each combination of three of those functions. Use “trigonometry” or list the three functions by name.

Comment: The elementary inverse trigonometric functions encompass arcsine, arccosine, and arctangent.

Comment: @DavidK I wouldn't say I expect special terms, but something that sums them up would work wonders in relaying what the application is focused on. More of common ground between them I suppose.

Comment: I agree with DavidK. The combination of three functions you list is rather arbitrary, there is no label other than trigonometry that describes them.

Comment: If you included arcsin with those (and I can't see why you wouldn't; $\arcsin(x) = \pi/2 - \arccos(x)$), perhaps you could say that you're graphing [sinusoids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) and their inverses

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Boom! That would be exactly what I am trying to accomplish! I have no issues including arcsin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comment thread, it seems that [sinusoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave) is the most precise descriptor for the kinds of graphs that you're looking for.